# Madeira vine watering

Tags: watering, vines

I have a little [madeira vine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anredera_cordifolia) plant in my room. How often do you recommend to water it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prefers moist soil, but that doesn't mean it likes to be wet all the time - it's the usual thing 'moist but well drained'. It's also a succulent so tolerates drought quite well, so I suggest you water when the surface of the potting medium feels just dry to the touch, but not shrunken from the sides of the pot, water it well and don't let it stand in water in any outer container or tray, so empty it after 30 minutes if water has collected. How often that's going to be is hard to say, depends on the temperature and conditions in your room.